# What fruit trees are suitable for growing in containers in a subtropical zone?

Tags: fruit-trees, plant-recommendations, pots

I live in Northern Australia, which is a subtropical zone. We always have temperatures above 20°C. We have two seasons:

- a dry season with no rain and temperatures ranging between 21°C and 32°C and with humidity around 60%.
- a wet season with lots of rain and temperatures ranging from 25°C to 33°C, and humidity over 80%.

I am thinking of growing some fruit trees. What can you guys recommend for this conditions? I am looking for something that is easy to grow as I am a newbie and can grow in large pots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want something a little different taste wise, then Guavas/Fejoas might be something to look into. They grow very quickly and produce a lot of fruit. They are tolerant of different soils (acid/alkaline, sandy/clay) so suitable for a beginner. They are pretty hungry so they do need fertilising, but that's all you would need to do with the soil. Many varieties would fruit twice a year in your climate. The major downside is that they are very susceptible to Queensland Fruit Fly, so you would need to net while the fruit is on the tree. If you are keeping the tree relatively short in a pot that might make it easier to do this.

Answer (score 3):

I found citrus trees very easy to grow in containers. It's fun to get a 'Buddah's Hand' lemon and make pickles out of the fruit which has a lot of rind.

Other nice varieties are Meyer lemon and the Kaffir and key limes for cooking related use.

Avocado and fig are other fine choices